# How do I loop through a nested context dictionary in Django when I have no idea the structure I will recieve

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a dictionary I am passing to a template that looks something like this:

```
{'leasee': {'respond': {'hour': True, 'day': True}, 'contact': {'phone': True, 'facebook': True, 'email': True, 'other': True, 'text': True}, 'licence': '987654321', 'help': {'beautySupplyProvider': True, 'photographer': True}, 'phoneNumber': '12345678910', 'name': 'Chris', 'certifications': {'yes': True, 'long': 'All of them'}, 'profession': {'massageTherapist': True, 'nailTechnician': True, 'barber': True}, 'amenities': {'receptionist': True, 'retailDisplayShelfSpace': True, 'long': 'some words', 'other': True, 'highTrafic': True}, 'email': 'chris@internet.com', 'circleData': '(45.5144493,-122.6710338) 400', 'compare': {'uniqueVsChic': '1', 'teamVsSolo': '1', 'familyVsUpscale': '8'}}}
```

I need it to be a list that looks like:

```
Key:
    Value
Key:
    Value
    Value
    Value
```

and so on.

The closest I can get is

```
{% for key, value in leasee.items %}
    <p> {{key}} </p>
    <ul>
    {% for k2, v2 in value.items %}
        <li> {{ k2 }} </li>
        {% for k3, v3 in v2.items %}
            <li>{{ k3 }}:{{ v3 }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

But keys that only have one value and not other dictionaries as values do not show up. How can I make this work?

I just want to add the answer to my question here in case anyone ever comes across this. Thanks to Animesh Sharma!

I had to create a template tag that determined the data type that I was looping through. It looks like this.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def data_type(value):
    if type(value) is dict:
        return 'dict'
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom template tag which returns the type of data.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def data_type(value):
    return type(value)
```

Then use it inside your template like this:

```
{% for key, value in leasee.items %}
    <p> {{key}} </p>
    <ul>
    {%if value|data_type == 'dict' %}
    {% for k2, v2 in value.items %}
        <li> {{ k2 }} </li>
        {%if v2|data_type == 'dict'%}
        {% for k3, v3 in v2.items %}
            <li>{{ k3 }}:{{ v3 }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
    {%else%}
    <li>{{v2}}</li>
    {%endif%}

{% endfor %}
{%else%}
<li>{{value}}</li>
{%endif%}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is just what I needed. I did have to make a change to the code.


`    from django import template
    
    register = template.Library()`
    
`from django import template`

`register = template.Library()`

@register.filter
def data_type(value):
    print(type(value))
    if type(value) is dict:
        return 'dict'
    return type(value)
`

Comment: To be more specific it is a template  `filter`, not a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to implement a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) for this.

And inside this tag you can render your data properly based on it's structure.